# How to open HTML file in browser in centos?

Tags: php, html, linux, browser, ip-address

I am accessing one system with ipaddress 192.168.1.41 as a server. In this system has one HTML file which is located at path **opt/openerp/apache/htdocs/index.html**. Now how can I access the html file in my local system browser ?

I tried with **192.168.1.41/index.html** but it does not work.

Can anyone help me how to access the file in my local browser

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put index.html in /var/www/ and try opening with the browser 192.168.1.41/index.html.  First check apache2 is installed
**Steps -**
1. sudo cp /etc/apache2/sites-available/default /etc/apache2/sites-available/site_name
2. Change the default document root and directory directive in the new file to new location.
3. sudo a2dissite default && sudo a2ensite mysite    [deactivate old site and activate new site]
4. sudo service apache2 restart

Comment: Yes, But how can I change the default web root path /var/www/ to opt/openerp/apache/htdocs/ ?